# Why doesn't conv.add work when console.log does when using an API

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

//EDIT: SOLVED. Code bellow shows my changed code and it works now.

when I use agent.add doesn't show anything while the console.log does.

```js
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const app = conversation();

var titels = [];

axios.get(`YOUR-API`)
  .then((result)=> {
    titels.push(result.data.categories[0].news[0].title);
    /* result.data.map(wordObj => {
      titels.push(wordObj.categories.news.title);
    });*/ 
  }); 
  
app.handle('rhymeHandler', conv => {
  console.log(titels[0]);
  conv.add(titels[0]); 
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);    

/* for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  conv.add(words[i]);
  } */
  //console.log(words);
```

Does anyone perhaps have any idea why this doesn't work?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not seems to occur within your async function. The code that Nick sent should work. So I think it has to do with something else. The error message tells me there are more than 2 simple responses defined, and Action on Google can't handle that.

I can see that you create an array containing multiple words in this function, and you are generating new simple responses by using `conv.add(word)`. So if the number of words in this array is higher than 2, the response is not valid.

So in order to fix the problem. You should make sure that `conv.add(word)` doesn't get called more than 2 times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that you are using a promise but not giving that promise to the intent handler, so it doesn't understand that it's asynchronous and so `conv` is returned synchronously.

The order of operations in your code is:

- `axios.get`

  - `result` is obtained
  - Iterate through `result`

    - log iteration
  - `addWords`
- Exit execution of flow

You don't need to assign the promise to a variable, but can instead return it directly within the scope of the intent handler. Additionally, your promise returns but doesn't actually resolve.

Here's how I would write it to manage the asynchronous behavior better:

```js
app.handle('rhymeHandler', conv => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    axios.get(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=book`)
      .then((result)=> {
        result.data.map(wordObj => {
          console.log(wordObj.word);
          words = [...words, wordObj.word];
        });
        addWords(conv);
        res(); // End promise
      });
  });
});
```

Additionally, if you are using Node 8, you can use the `async`/`await` keywords to streamline this intent handler.

```js
app.handle('rhymeHandler', async conv => {
  const result = await axios.get(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=book`)
  result.data.map(wordObj => {
    console.log(wordObj.word);
    words = [...words, wordObj.word];
  });
  addWords(conv);
});
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your comment. I have tried both options, the first one with node 10 and the second one with node 8. However, with both versions I get the following errors: -Error: could not handle the request\n (when using the first code snippet) and -Error adding simple response: Two simple responses already defined (when using the second code snippet.